# How to convert JSON to HashMap and compare them?

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap, gson

I have a json stored in a DB like this,

```
"supported_iso_codes":[
 {
      "EUR": "978",
      "USD": "840"
    }

],
```

To access this in my app code, I do something like this..

```
getISOProfileDB.getSupportedISOCodes();
```

I have a string which the user inputs(provides input string like EUR, USD,etc). How can I convert the above json to a HashMap and compare it with another string? What I am trying to achieve is,

1. Compare Key part of json to user input string(EUR).
2. If both of them match,
3. Parse the value part of json and store it in a variable.

Below is what I'm trying to achieve,

```
   tran.setCurrency(hashMapOfJson.get(currencyString));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Gson :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}
```

And then :

```
Map<String, Object> supported_iso_codes = new Gson().fromJson(getISOProfileDB.getSupportedISOCodes(), new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>(){}.getType();
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> isoCodesMapList = gson.fromJson(data, type);
        System.out.println(arrayList);
```

then for getting the user selected currency you can do

```
isoCodesMapList.get(userSelectedCurrency);
```

Hope this helps:)

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using JSONObject (Jsonobject.org) or Gson.

Comment: You answer would be improved by giving an example that's relevant to the OP's code.  As it currently exists, your "answer" is more of a comment than a solution.